# NetLogo, mapping an array of multidimensional variables

Tags: netlogo, agent-based-modeling

I need to estimate the mean value in a network for each dimension of a 3-dimension variable (`var_1`) . The code I've written doesn't quite do the trick:

```
    set avg-network map mean ([var_1] of turtles)
```

What this does is calculating the average for all three dimensions of each turtle instead of the average for each dimension for all turtles. That is:

`Turtle0 [0 0 0]
 Turtle1 [1 1 1]
 Turtle2 [2 2 2]
 Turtle3 [3 3 3]`

Gives `[0 1 2 3]`instead of `[2 2 2]`which is what I am after...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a way using the `matrix` extension. What I do is:

```
extensions [ matrix ]

to-report temp-matrix
let m matrix:from-row-list ([var_1] of turtles)
report m
end

to go
  let i 0
  set avg-network n-values 3 [0]
  repeat 3 [
    set avg-network replace-item i avg-network (mean matrix:get-column temp-matrix i)
    set i (i + 1)  
  ]
end
```

Not the most elegant but it does the trick. If anyone knows another way I am happy to hear!